# tfidf.idf_ what is meaning of this in the code

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False, )
tfidf.fit_transform(questions)

## dict key:word and value:tf-idf score

word2tfidf = dict(zip(tfidf.get_feature_names(), tfidf.idf_))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

```
idf_: array of shape (n_features,)
The inverse document frequency (IDF) vector; only defined if use_idf is True.
```